# What is this wall finishing?

Tags: finishing

What is this wall finishing?

It looks like a brick veneer, or wall paper; or is it perhaps a plaster?

If plaster, how would I attain this pattern?

I doubt it's painted brick, but I could be wrong.

[image]
Seen at https://www.thespruce.com/living-room-accent-walls-4135943

Comment: Would say painted over brick.  Difficult design for a plaster wall, and lack of colour differences for other guesses.

Comment: Any join lines? Any repeated pattern? Otherwise looks like painted brick.

Comment: https://www.mybluestarantiques.com/product/brick-texture-roller/

Comment: @Kris  If they had a few different roller designs, so pattern does not repeat, would be perfect for an answer.  Did not know of.

Comment: There is another method involving faux brick panels and joint compound.   https://thesavvysparrow.com/diy-faux-brick-wall/

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Brewster-Paintable-Belden-Brick-Texture-Vinyl-Peelable-Wallpaper-Covers-56-4-sq-ft-497-99423/206977842                               Then there are a number of paintable expanded vinyl wall coverings that can give the look of an old brick wall

Comment: @Kris, great suggestions, would make for a good answer!

Answer (score 3):

Sure looks like **painted brick**.

- Pattern matches size/shape of typical bricks
- The unevenness of the pattern points to a somewhat older brick wall.
- The room may have been outside (e.g., an originally open porch) and then enclosed and/or extended from the existing house. Instead of adding a full layer of studs/drywall/etc., easier to just paint over to hide a lot of the imperfections.
- If this were a veneer/"fake brick" wall, the pattern would almost certainly be much closer to "perfect".